# Is there way to retrieve auto incremented primary key after submission of transaction?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, table

I'm working on sample dApp application to understand the working of multi_index table in EOS smart contract.
I have defined two multi_index table. The primary key of table1 is auto incremented using "primary_key()". The table two has one column which refers to primary key of table1 (like foreign key in DB). I have a sequence where I first add an entry to table1 using eos-go and then need to create an entry in table2 with retrieving inserted primary_key in the table1. I don't find a way to fetch the auto incremented primary key after completing create transaction to table1.

Is there any way to fetch/return last inserted primary key like in sql in EOS smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

There is an improvement that makes action can have return value, but not applied to mainnet yet. After its applying, you can check that value from action_receipt.

Current feasible solution is making a table storing the result of last executed action and reading it.

```
auto it = some_table_index.emplace(payer, [&](auto& row) {
   row.id = some_table_index.available_primary_key();
   /* ... */
});

// you can access last incremented key by "it->primary_key()"
// make independent multi_index table or singleton to store this value
```